# Как удалять файлы в /usr/local/bin?

Tags: ubuntu

Использовал sudo для добавления файла в `/usr/local/bin`.

Как теперь удалить оттуда файл?

Comment: Ну наверное sudo rm /usr/local/bin/<имя файла>

Comment: Возможно не самый лучший совет для новичка, но я для работы рутом просто делаю `sudo bash`  (в крайнем случае переставите систему)

Comment: Спасибо! Надо читать короче книгу. Много вопросов у меня)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

точно так же — «используя sudo»:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/файл
```

Comment: Спасибо. Решил почитать Основы Lunux от основателя Gentoo. А то у меня просто масса глупых вопросов)